# Getting the active working set programatically in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Can anyone please tell me how to get the current or active working set and also to get all the projects in the working set in IProject type? I am trying to achieve it by using the below code -

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
IWorkingSetManager manager = window.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();
IWorkingSet[] workingSets = manager.getWorkingSets();
```

This will get me all the working sets that are present in eclipse? The IWorkingSet.getElements() provides all the project details in the IAdaptable type which I cannot cast into IProject?

Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert an `IAdaptable` value to an `IProject` using:

```
IProject project = (IProject)adaptable.getAdapter(IProject.class);
```

I am not sure if the working set element provides an adapter directly to `IProject`, you might need to use:

```
IResource resource = (IResource)adaptable.getAdapter(IResources.class);

if (resource instanceof IProject)
 {
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. It worked perfectly. I am learning a lot from you. The active working set should be present at the first of the list of working sets returned by the getRecentWorkingSets() function, atleast according to the theory present in eclipse bibliography but it didnt workout. Anyways, thank you very much for your timely help.

Comment: `IWorkbenchPage` has a `getWorkingSet` but this is deprecated as a global working set is now discouraged, instead individual views each have a separate active working set.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed reply.. Sure, Now I understand.. vogella rcp tutorials is a good start for these topics